# Reloading a specific view MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I work on a webpage which has a shopping basket.
My problem is that the shopping basket doesn't show the number of elements when I add a new item. It shows only after I reload the page manually. But I need to show the number of items right after I add a new item.

This is the button which add the new item to basket:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addtoBasket(this)" id="addToBasket" data-id=@c.ID>Add</button>
```

This is the ajax call:

```
 <script>
  function addtoBasket(obj) {
    var $button = $(obj);
    var testId = $button.data("id"); //reading the data-id of clicked button
    var UrlSettings = {
        url: '@Url.Action("SetShoppingCartElement", "Purchase")'
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: UrlSettings.url,
        data: { 'id': testId },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {                
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        }
    });

}
```

and this is my ActionResult in controller:

```
public ActionResult SetShoppingCartElement(string id)
    {
        int productId = int.TryParse(id, out productId) ? productId : 0;

        Product product = productRepository.GetProductByID(productId);

        List<Product> list = HttpContext.Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<Product>;
        if (list == null)
            list = new List<Product>();

        bool alreadyExists = list.Any(x => x.Id == product.Id);
        if (!alreadyExists)
        {
            list.Add(product);
            Session["ShoppingCart"] = list;
            Session["ShoppingCartCount"] = list.Count;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The Session["ShoppingCartCount"] is set correctly, but it is not showing the result only after a page refresh. The Session["ShoppingCartCount"] is displayed on a Layout view. The location.reload() doesn't fix my problem. Can you advise how to resolve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I would hold cart items in javascript array and update HTML that is showing cart items count depending on that array's length

Comment: is the result of SetShoppingCarElement a Partial View? If so, you can return that, and and in the "success" function of your ajax you can replace the HTML of the existing shopping cart with the HTML returned from the partial view. Or you could just return JSON from the ajax call containing the necessary data to display the cart, and control the actual rendering entirely on the Javascript side